# No sound input when using internal microphone

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Acer Swift SF314-54 and I can't get the internal microphone to detect sound.

Alsamixer shows my card as a HDA Intel PCH and the chip as a Realtek ALC256.

I've found a few conversations online where the fix was to modify  `etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` by adding `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic` at the end of it but unfortunately it apparently only works if plugging in an external microphone.

Would there be anything I could do to use the inbuilt microphone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this thread while desperately searching for a solution to the microphone which at some point stopped working on an Asus laptop running Ubuntu 21.10 / 22.04. This answer from laugeo solved the problem for me:

*Also check "configuration" tab is showing "duplex" mode for your device.*

After I changed the profile from "Analog Stereo Output" to "Analog Stereo Duplex" in pavucontrol, the microphone started working again, meaning that an additional device ("Built-in Audio Analog Stereo", port "Internal Microphone") now shows up on the Input Devices tab and captures ambient audio.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's actually the fix that I had to make as well.

Answer (score 0):

- In alsamixer, press F4 to display capture devices and check internal mic is selected for capture ,  and if level is ok.
- Alternatively install pavucontrol (pulseaudio volume control) and search/select  mic  input  in "input devices"  . Also check "configuration" tab  is showing "duplex" mode for your device.
- Try `options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer`  in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf     (this is closest option for your pc from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/tree/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst)) .
  Other possible option would be `options snd-hda-intel model=alc256-asus-mic`.
  Reboot after changing option as this is kernel parameter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I did both things and unfortunately it did not help. Is there anything I could do?

Comment: added 3rd possible fix

Comment: When I added the model=alc255-acer line, settings were not even showing an internal mic anymore. The model=alc256-asus-mic got me a bit of white noise, but no detection of sounds.