# Internal Mic is not working on a ASUS TUF Laptop (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: sound, microphone

Disclaimer: this is my first experience with Linux so I'm a complete beginner!

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, the internal microphone is not working, but when an external USB microphone is plugged in, that does work. After seeing another suggestion, I opened alsamixer and when I checked the 'capture view', it told me that "this sound device does not have any sound controls". Does this mean this is a driver issue?

Answer (score 0):

See this issue:

[No sound input when using internal microphone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287353/no-sound-input-when-using-internal-microphone)

Also, I have found instances where my built-in audio type has been set to "Stereo" rather than "Duplex". Duplex is needed for both input and output.

In KDE it's Settings > Audio > Speakers (Built-in...). Not sure how to get there in Gnome.